# I am having trouble updating the value of a variable

Tags: python

This is a python hangman program. I want the variable guesses_left to decrease by 1 when the user guesses an incorrect answer. It stays at 9 incorrect guesses left no matter what is guessed. How do I fix this so that it decreases by 1 all the way down to 0? Thanks!

```
#initializes the secret word and starts with empty dashes list
secret_word = "eggplant"
dashes_list = []
def get_guess(guesses_left):
    #prompts user for a guess
    guess = input("Guess: ")
    dashes = "-"
    #if the guess is not one character
    if len(guess) != 1:
        print ("Your guess must have exactly one character!")
    #if the guess is not lowercase
    elif not guess.islower():
        print ("Your guess must be a lowercase letter!")
    #assigns this position_of_letter variable to be used later
    position_of_letter = 0
    for letter in secret_word:
            if guess == letter:
                print ("Letter is in secret word.")
                update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, guess)
                return
            else:
                position_of_letter += 1
                if position_of_letter == len(secret_word):
                    print ("Letter is not in the secret word.")
                    if guesses_left==0:
                        print("You lose. The word was "+secret_word)
                        exit()
                    guesses_left=guesses_left-1
                    print (str(guesses_left)+" incorrect guesses left.")
#This goes through the word and makes sure to update
#the dashes at the right place
def update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, guess):
    position_of_letter_dashes_list = 0
    for letter in secret_word:
        if letter == guess:
            dashes_list[position_of_letter_dashes_list] = guess
        position_of_letter_dashes_list += 1

#adds a dash mark for each letter so there is now a list of dashes    
for i in range(len(secret_word)):
    dashes_list.append("-")
#The .join breaks the dashes list into a continuous string of dashes
#The "" is there so that nothing comes before each dash
guesses_left=10
while True:
    print ("".join(dashes_list))
    get_guess(guesses_left)
    if "-" not in dashes_list:
        print("Congrats! You win. The word was "+secret_word+".")
        break
```

Comment: you always pass in `10` to your `get_guess` function, and it doesn't return anything. Probably, you want to `return guesses_left` and then from the call, do  `guesses_left = get_guess(guesses_left)`. In the future, **please provide a [mcve]** You could have reproduced this issue with a very simple example, most of the code you provided is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently you pass `guesses_left` into `get_guess` as an argument and when you decrement it, you don't affect the global variable. You can rectify this by returning the number of guesses left from `get_guess` and storing this into `guesses_left`, by updating the following (marked) lines:

```
if len(guess) != 1:
    print ("Your guess must have exactly one character!")
    return guesses_left  # THIS LINE
#if the guess is not lowercase
elif not guess.islower():
    print ("Your guess must be a lowercase letter!")
    return guesses_left  # THIS LINE
    #assigns this position_of_letter variable to be used later
position_of_letter = 0
for letter in secret_word:
    if guess == letter:
          print ("Letter is in secret word.")
          update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, guess)
          return guesses_left  # THIS LINE
    else:
          position_of_letter += 1
          if position_of_letter == len(secret_word):
               print ("Letter is not in the secret word.")
               if guesses_left==0:
                    print("You lose. The word was "+secret_word)
                    exit()
               guesses_left=guesses_left-1
               print (str(guesses_left)+" incorrect guesses left.")
               return guesses_left  # THIS LINE
...
while True:
    guesses_left = get_guess(guesses_left)  # THIS LINE
    if "-" not in dashes_list:
        print("Congrats! You win. The word was "+secret_word+".")
        break
```